# Динамическое создание переменных

Tags: python

Имеется словарь и нужно создавать переменные со значением ключа,они будут равны значению этого ключа. Количество ключей не известно
Например:

```
d = {'h1':'name1', 'h2':'name2'}
print(h1, h2) 
#name1 name2
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нет крайней необходимости создавать беспорядок имен переменных, я бы просто использовал словарь, где вы можете динамически создавать имена ключей и связывать значение с каждым.

```
    a = {}
k = 0
while k < 10:
    # dynamically create key
    key = ...
    # calculate value
    value = ...
    a[key] = value 
    k += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Если для общего развития, то можно вот так.

```
d = {'h1':'name1', 'h2':'name2'}

for key, value in d.items():
    globals()[key] = value

print(h1, h2)
```

Но вообще динамическое создание переменных - это очень плохая практика.
Стоит задуматься о реализации через ассоциативные структуры данных. Например, словарь.

Answer (score 1):

```py
d = {
    # Какой то словарь
}
globals().update(d)
```

Это добавит словарь со всеми значениями к глобальным переменным.
А если понадобятся локальные, то `globals` заменяет на `locals`.
А вообще, лучше просто использовать словарь вместо захламления пространства имен

Comment: Когда искал решение, люди тоже говорили про использование словаря. Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: @akimochev вместо того, чтобы создавать переменную с именем и значением из словаря оставьте его в исходном виде, и когда вам нужно обратиться к "переменной" - обращайтесь к словарю при помощи d[h1].

Comment: Понял, благодарю.